# Toggle needs to work only on parent div, not child div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am simulating a pop up window that fades the background out. I do this by simply toggling a div that fills the whole screen. I would like to be able to close the pop up by clicking the outside background, but not when you click on the new content area, which is what is currently happening. My code:

JS:

```
function popbox() {
    $('#overbox').toggle();
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="popbox" onclick="popbox()"> Click Here </div>

<div id="overbox" onclick="popbox()">
     <div id="infobox1">
          <p>This is a new box</p>
          <br />
          <p>hello </p>
          <br/><br/>
          <p style="color:blue;text-align:center;cursor:pointer;" onclick="popbox()">close</p>
     </div><!-- end infobox1 --> 
</div> <!-- end overbox -->
```

CSS:

```
#overbox {
     position: fixed;
     top: 0px;
     left: 0px;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%; 
     background: rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.5);
     z-index: 999999;
     display: none;
}

#infobox1 {
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    left: 35%;
    top: 20%;
    height: 300px;
     width: 400px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.popbox {
     cursor: pointer;
     color: black;
     border: 1px solid gray;
     padding: 5px; 10px;
     background: ghostwhite;
     display: inline-block;
}
```

JSFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/RrJsC/

Again, I want it to toggle only when you click the faded background or "close" (which isnt working in the jsfiddle but is on my site), but not when you click inside the white box that it contains. 
After some research it seems like I might be looking for .stopPropagation(), but I haven't been able to get it to work at all.

Comment: I believe I have actually figured out a weird workaround. It seems like the nested toggles are canceling each other out, so if I simply add another onclick="popbox()" to the infobox1 id, it toggles it OFF first from the overbox id, and then immediately toggles it back ON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to work using jQuery's event handlers:

```
$('#container').on('click', '.popbox, #overbox', function(e){   
  $('#overbox').toggle();
 });
 $('#container').on('click', '#infobox1', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
 });
```

I replaced `document` with `'#container'` for better performance. You should wrap all your divs in `<div id="container">...</div>` so the the callback doesn't fire on the dom every time there is a click (even thought that callback is only called when the selector matches).

You'll also need to get rid of your `onclick` html attributes, because they will throw an error if that function is not defined.

Comment: This is unfortunately not working for me. With this, when I click on the .popbox p, nothing happens.

Comment: did you get rid of the `onclick` attribute? that would throw an error and nothing would fire. http://jsfiddle.net/RrJsC/

Comment: I did, but I actually just replied to my own question with a decent solution I found. Regardless, thank you for your help.

Comment: @user1925805 The answer posted by Eric H actually works right and solves your problem.  Consider giving him some credit for his efforts to help you.

Comment: I see that Eric's solution is working on the jsfiddle, and it certainly is a better way of solving my problem, but it is still not actually working on my site. I can't seem to figure out why, but I have marked his answer as useful.

Comment: @EricH. So After some experimentation, I was able to finally get it to work on my site. The problem is I was putting the code in an external JS file, and it only worked when I put it in the head section of the page it was effecting. Do you have any insight as to why this would be the case?

Comment: my first guess would be that the script is not loading properly. Try to `console.log` something and see if it runs. If that's not it, maybe wrapping the code in a '$(document).ready' callback. Also, see my edits above about adding a container to not overload the document with callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand well your problem.

If it is the case, you should have this:

```
<div id="overbox">
```

instead of this:

```
<div id="overbox" onclick="popbox()">
```

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/RrJsC/2/) is the updated jsfiddle